# I am not able to understand Scala identity call using futures

Tags: scala, future

I was messing around with Predef identity function and Futures and got to this expression:

```
identity(_: Future[A])
```

This returns `Future[A] => Future[A]` but i was expecting just `Future[A]`

The Identity method is just returns the input so i wonder just what exactly does `_: Future[A]` mean.

Comment: Did you write this method yourself or was this from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identity` in Predef is defined as follow:

```
def identity[A](x: A): A = x
```

As you can see, it is a method. When you write something like the following:

```
val f = identity(_: Future[Int])
```

you're transforming a method, `identity`, into a function of type `Future[Int] => Future[Int]`. The `_: Future[Int]` part is called type ascription and tells the compiler that the type `A` of `identity` is `Future[Int]`.

The process of transforming a method into a function goes by the name of eta expansion.

P.S.: You could have done the same thing as follow:

```
val f = identity[Future[Int]] _
```

Comment: Yeah I realized the answer after playing with it for a while and I also did the last example you showed just to be sure. If I am correct, we are currying the identity function without passing any arguments but dictating that the parameterized type is Future, right?

Comment: You're not currying, that way you're using eta expansion to convert a method into a function.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `_: Future[A]` is representing a function that takes a single parameter of type `Future[A]` and returns it.

Similarly to how in `List(1,2).map(_.toString)` the parameter to map expands to `x => x.toString`, or a function that takes a single parameter, and calls `toString` on it.

In your case, you're not calling any methods on it. You're just specifying the type of the parameter (of the passed function, not identity) So:

```
identity(_: Future[A])
```

expands to

```
identity((x: Future[A]) => x)
```

which is a `Future[A] => Future[A]`

Comment: No, it expands to `(x: Future[A]) => identity(x)`.